# kafka-server-start.bat not running and no logs are reported

Tags: apache-kafka

I try to install kafka on window.
I followed the steps which are in this article . https://dzone.com/articles/running-apache-kafka-on-windows-os

But when I try to start the kafka server I don't get the same result .

I get this output
[image]

Instead of that

[image]

is there anyone who knows where the problem comes from?
**Thank you**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the `.bat` file as executable (note the `.` in hte beginning):

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
```

---

Furthermore, you also need to add `C:\Windows\System32` in `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I did what you say but I get now this error : ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception (kafka.Kafka$)
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: .\config\server.properties

Comment: .Thank you I resolved the problem by ".\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties"